# Visual studio 2010 assembly references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, projects-and-solutions

I've got a project on a computer with installed devexpress line for win forms. In VS2010 I add references to some of devexpress .dll(s) and mark those references as 'Copy Local' and build project. Than I send a folder with a project to another user whose machine has not installed devexpress on it. When he opens the solution all devexpress references are shown as broken and the assembly won't compile.

The output is as the following:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): 
warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
 "DevExpress.Data.v13.1, Version=13.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a". 
Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. 
If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

How to  add references to the assembly correctly so as I can open it on a machine with no such .dll(s) installed?

Comment: Trying not a kick in a wide open door: that programmer needs to purchase a license from DevExpress as well.  Replacing the references in the project to the copies you supplied ought to get him somewhere.  It is however very unlikely that design-time support will work.

Comment: Suppose it were not DevX but another .dll. If it is not installed in GUC there all the same must be some way to add this dll to the project with relative path, mustn't it? Otherwise on different machine different users have to determine local path to this dll for each machine differently.

Comment: The guy will have no problem *executing* the program you sent him.  Building it is a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to add the references via *Add Reference... / Browse*. In the csproj file for your project you should have something like:

```
<Reference Include="Name.Of.Assembly">
    <HintPath>Relative\Path\ToAssemblyFile.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**BUT** VisualStudio tries to be smart and adds the Reference to the installed assemblies, even if you choose *Browse...* to add them.
You can either:

1. Not install the DevExpress package and only copy the DLLs to your development machine
2. Manually edit the .csproj file

Either way, you need to keep the DLLs somewhere. I usually put them under source control.

Answer (score 0):

"Copy Local" option is copying files to the published directories after building process.

You can include these dlls in the separated solution folder, reference VisualStudio to them and commit this folder with solution to svn or tfs.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you should add the DevExpress (or other third-party) assemblies to a folder under your solution root directory, then reference the assemblies in this folder rather than referencing the DevExpress install directory.

You should also add the third-party assemblies to source control, so they're available to all developers.

If the other developer hasn't installed a DevExpress license, it will still build, but will display a nag screen at runtime.